# How do I create a SQL DELETE statement to delete rows in a 3rd table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is the structure of my SQLite database:
[image]

I am trying to delete ALL of the OrderData that belongs to a select OrderInfo.Cust_ID which belongs to a particular CustData.Cust_ID.  This is my DELETE statement, which gives me the error: "no such column: CustData.Customer_ID"

```
DELETE FROM OrderData
   WHERE CustData.Customer_ID = OrderInfo.Cust_ID 
   AND OrderData.Order_ID = OrderInfo.Order_ID 
   AND CustData.Bus_Name = 'Albertsons'
```

I know that SQLite does NOT support JOINs in a DELETE statement, so I'm left with WHERE and ANDs; can someone please tell me the correct way to word this?

Comment: You could try a subquery with an IN clause.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try a subquery with an IN clause. Something like:

```
DELETE FROM OrderData WHERE OrderData.Order_ID IN
(SELECT OrderInfo.Order_ID 
FROM OrderInfo
JOIN CustData on OrderData.Order_ID = OrderInfo.Order_ID 
WHERE CustData.Bus_Name = 'Albertsons')
```

to test the query before deleting just do this: (will return all rows that would be deleted by the delete query)

```
SELECT * FROM OrderData WHERE OrderData.Order_ID IN
(SELECT OrderInfo.Order_ID 
FROM OrderInfo
JOIN CustData on OrderData.Order_ID = OrderInfo.Order_ID 
WHERE CustData.Bus_Name = 'Albertsons')
```

Comment: Paul:  I have never used a subquery with an IN clause (SQLite docs don't even mention it)... so I was wondering if you could take a moment and fill in what goes in "some_table" and "some_other_table"?  Also, a good tutorial on subqueries (aimed at SQLite) would be appreciated (I don't want to go away from this not knowing what I'm doing!) :D

Comment: @spokane-dude: I updated the answer. I think it's actually quite similar to what davids posted... I also added a test query to use before trying the actual deletes. It should work because the DELETE does not actually perform a JOIN. The JOIN is isolated in the subquery which returns all the IDs into the IN clause of the top-level query.

Comment: @spokane-dude: Oops. Had an issue in the queries. Edited the answer. Please try again.

Comment: This is apparently it... but I don't have anything in the OrderData table... thank you for your help... I'll but some data in the table and see where this goes... :D

SELECT * FROM OrderData WHERE OrderData.Order_ID IN
(SELECT OrderInfo.Order_ID 
FROM OrderInfo
JOIN CustData on OrderData.Order_ID = OrderInfo.Order_ID 
WHERE CustData.Bus_Name = 'Prager Software')

Comment: @spokane-dude: Another oops. Try again.

Comment: Thanks Paul... I appreciate your time.. :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12042/discussion-between-paul-sasik-and-spokane-dude)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

> SQLite (under v3.6.19) does not support foreign key constraints

, but you can use `triggers` for example
Check [this](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ForeignKeyTriggers) it will help you.

If you have v 3.6.19, it already support foreign constraints with ON `UPDATE` or `DELETE CASCADE`
Read [SQLite Foreign Key Support](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

**EDIT:**

**OR like wrote @Paul Sasik**

Answer (score 0):

try

```
DELETE FROM OrderData
WHERE OrderData.Order_ID IN (SELECT oi.Order_ID FROM OrderInfo oi 
  INNER JOIN CustData cd ON oi.Cust_id = cd.Customer_Id WHERE cd.Bus_Name='Albertsons')
```

Comment: This is SQLite... can't use JOINs with DELETE in SQLite... thanks anyway

Comment: I am not familiar with SQLite, but the join is on a subquery, does that not make a difference?

Comment: My comment is basically the same as @Paul Sasik, just with your columns and tables.